# httpd reverse-proxy in front traefik ingress from kubernetes

Tags: apache, kubernetes, traefik-ingress

I have a kubernetes cluster. I am using traefik to create ingress.

Traefik is creating the ingress like the following name app1.192.168.0.10.nip.io

I would like set the httpd reverse proxy in front of traefik.

Code example from HTTPD:

### app1

ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /kubernetes/app1 http://app1.192.168.0.10.nip.io:80

ProxyPassReverse /kubernetes/app1 http://app1.192.168.0.10.nip.io:80

In the browser, I have tried https://somedomain.com/kubernetes/app1 and it return 404, but if I use http://app1.192.168.0.10.nip.io, the browser return the content.

I have other proxypass (no kubernetes) and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved:

I have put de root path from reverse proxy to root path ingress but I have modified the traefik with another configuration.